# Selenium Problem with automatic sorting of product prices on the shopping site and problem of obtaining product information

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Part of price tracker code :

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
import inspect
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Get the search term and tracking period from the user
search_term = input("Please enter the name of the product you want to search: ")
months =input("Please enter the number of months you want to track the product: ")

# To ensure that the user enters a non-string value 
while not months.isdigit():
    print("Warning: Please enter a valid integer value for the number of months.")
    months = input("Please enter the number of months you want to track the product: ")
months = int(months)

# Start the web driver and go to the Hepsiburada homepage
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)


module_path="C:/Users/Desktop/hepsiburada_price_tracker/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=module_path,options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.hepsiburada.com/")

# Accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
sleep(3)



# Enter the search term in the search box and press Enter
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
search_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'theme-IYtZzqYPto8PhOx3ku3c')))

search_box.send_keys(search_term)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for search results and select the first product
sleep(3)  # Sayfanın yüklenmesi için birkaç saniye bekleyin

# Click on the order button
driver.find_element_by_class_name('horizontalSortingBar-Ce404X9mUYVCRa5bjV4D').click()
sleep(3)

# Sort by increasing price
driver.find_element_by_class_name('horizontalSortingBar-PkoDOH7UsCwBrQaQx9bn').click()
sleep(3)

# Get the link, name, and price of the first product in the search results
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@data-test-id='product-card-name']")
if not results:
    print("Sorry, we could not find the product you were looking for.")
    #driver.quit()
else:
    first_result0 = results[0]
    first_result= first_result0.text
    print(first_result)
    product_link = first_result.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@data-productid]")
    product_url = product_link.get_attribute("href")
    product_name = first_result.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3").text
    print("The product selected from the search results is {}: {}".format(product_name, product_url))
```

Hello, I am trying to get the information of the lowest price of the specific product searched from the website Hepsiburada.com.tr like this: arko krem 20 cc (arko cream 20cc), but I have 2  problems related with each other.

1. When you go to the site manually and sort the products in ascending price, it sorts correctly, but when you test it automatically, it doesn't sort. Actually the code is clicking the right buttons(Sıralama>order, artan>ascending) but the ordering is wrong. Is this something fixable?
2. I could not find the number of products on the page (eg 115 for 20 cc of arko krem (arko cream) ), the links and the names of the sellers. I want to get this information collectively, then I want to get the first result in the list separately, as I sort the prices of the product from smallest to largest How can I access them with selenium?

I have (first_result) information, but I can't handle other information from here.

**Price ordered as manually:**

[image]

**Seller's name:**
[image]

Comment: 1. You're using deprecated syntax(`find_element_by_*`). 2. You're not using Waits. 3. After you interact with the page and change anything in it, be it  content or item order, you need to re-read the page content, to get the updated data. [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) is quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using Chrome, Edge and Firefox webdrivers, but all have one big problem, they don't load new articles as you scroll down or as you click the load more button. Luckily I found a working alternative, it is called undetected selenium.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false') # disable images so that pages load faster
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

search_term = 'pınar süt 1lt'
url = 'https://www.hepsiburada.com/ara?q=' + search_term.replace(' ','+')
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# load all products
number_of_products = int(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'searchResultSummaryBar-AVnHBWRNB0_veFy34hco')))[1].text)
number_of_loaded_products = 0
while number_of_loaded_products < number_of_products:
    loaded_products = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li[class*=productListContent][id]')))
    number_of_loaded_products = len(loaded_products)
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', loaded_products[-1])

# Get the link, name, price and seller of all the products
product = {key:[] for key in ['name','price','seller','url']}
product['name']  = [h3.text for h3 in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3[data-test-id=product-card-name]')]
product['url']   = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class*=ProductCard]')]
product['price'] = [float(div.text.replace('TL','').replace(',','.')) for div in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-test-id=price-current-price]')]
for i,url in enumerate(product['url']):
    print(f'Search seller names {i+1}/{number_of_loaded_products}', end='\r')
    driver.get(url)
    product['seller'] += [wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.seller a'))).text]
    product['url'][i] = driver.current_url # useful to replace some long urls

# Sort by price in ascending order
import pandas as pd
product = pd.DataFrame(product).sort_values(by='price').to_dict('list')

print(f"\nThe product selected from the search results is:"+
      f"\nname:   {product['name'][0]}"+
      f"\nprice:  {product['price'][0]}"+
      f"\nseller: {product['seller'][0]}"+
      f"\nurl:    {product['url'][0]}")
```

Output

```
Search seller names 37/37
The product selected from the search results is:
name:   Pınar Yağlı Süt 1 L
price:  27.9
seller: PınarOnline
url:    https://www.hepsiburada.com/pinar-yagli-sut-1-l-p-ZYBICN9286394?magaza=P%C4%B1narOnline
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the code for a different product (pınar süt 1lt). The site says it found 37 products in ascending order (the number of products changing by ordering from 33 to 37), but when I counted, 33 products appear on the page manually. number_of_loaded_products variable also outputs as 34 in the code. How we can solve this problem? @sound wave I couldn't get out of work

Comment: @murattaşçı There was a little mistake in the xpath of `loaded_products`, I corrected it and now it gives 33 products. About the 37 I noticed a strange problem. If you search `pınar süt 1lt` the site says "33 ürün bulduk" but if you manually count them there are 37. Then if you sort them in ascending order the site says "37 ürün bulduk" but if you manually count them there are 33. So it is a problem of the site

Comment: @murattaşçı So since sorting seems to remove products, I think the best thing to do is to scrape all products without sorting on the site, then in the end I create a pandas dataframe and sort it based on the prices